# Applying animations while changing visibility of a view

Tags: android, animation

I am having a HorizontalScrollView in my application and I am playing with its visibility very frequently(VISIBLE and GONE). So what I want is, instead of suddenly making it visible and invisible, can I apply some kind of animation or something so that it will start becoming visible and invisible in a sliding manner ?

Any help or suggestions would be highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you want to slide it to up,down,right,left direction and make it become invisible, you could use translate animation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try this:

```
Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,1000);
animation.setDuration(1000);
yourButtonorImage.startAnimation(animation);
```

To make it visible or invisible you could use setAnimationListener. In onAnimationEnd, make it visible or invisible. NOt sure if this is what you meant..Hope it helps..

Comment: Hey Thanks for replying first.
I was trying the same with xml, but the problem I am facing right now is, I want to hide the the same view on which I am applying the animation. And this is not working inside animation listener. (Problem is with same view, if I try to hide some other view, its works). Any solutions ?

Comment: It worked. Visibility gone is not working, but invisible is working. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try this..

```
youView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(youView, "alpha", 0f, 1f);
anim.setDuration(1000);
anim.start();
```

Api Level Restrictions Applied.